# NSDateComponents wrapping

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, word-wrap, nsdatecomponents

here is the set up:

```
NSDateComponents* temporalComponents;

temporalComponents = [theDateComponents copy];  //another component set to todays date.

[temporalComponents setDay:   [temporalComponents day] + (offset * 7)]
```

if i output the result of the components it shows that days are correctly added, for instance 21 days.

```
"<NSDateComponents: 0x6a48820>\n    Calendar Year: 2012\n    Month: 2\n    Day: 49\n    Hour: 13\n    Minute: 12"
```

but of course i want it to have this corrected “wrapped” component list, where the month is incremented and day is corrected..  (mainly because i do further manipulation where i may replace a whole component, rather than just adding to the component)  in otherwords my final product is a NSDateComponent,  so that it can be manipulated further.

```
"<NSDateComponents: 0x6a48820>\n    Calendar Year: 2012\n    Month: 3\n    Day: 20\n    Hour: 13\n    Minute: 12"
```

right now i am doing this to correctly wrap the days (and what ever else needs wrapped)

```
NSDate* tempDate = [CURRENTC dateFromComponents:temporalComponents];

temporalComponents2 = [CURRENTC components:unitFlags fromDate:tempDate];

[theDatesArray addObject: temporalComponents2];
```

is there any better way?  without having to go to a date, and back to component.  I’ve looked for a better way without success, perhaps i am searching with wrong terms.

Answer (score 0):

The provided means for adding a given offset to a given date is to use `NSCalendar`'s [`dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateByAddingComponents%3atoDate%3aoptions%3a). So you'd do something like this:

```
NSDateComponents *daysToAdd = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
daysToAdd.day = 23;

NSDate *derivedData =
      [CURRENTC dateByAddingComponents:daysToAdd
                toDate:sourceDate
                options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
```

With the implicit assumption being that you generally store things as `NSDate`'s, with `NSDateComponents` being the helper that allows you to manipulate them relative to a given `NSCalendar`.

So in your case I don't think you can do any better than you're doing, because you're using what Apple consider the helper as the actual storage.

Comment: my main purpose is to save the components so that i can keep adding and subtracting,  and not have to go through NSDate,  this does not save any steps,  nor the extra call to NSDate...

Comment: @hokkuk I'm aware of that, and have explained how my answer is helpful with respect to your question in the final paragraph.

Comment: I would store the date, except that it needs to be converted to a component to manipulate again. for instance i may replace the entire year component in the future rather than just adding to it and then restoring it back where it saved. It appears to me that the components in this case of multiple manipulation and store again with a new value, is the path of least resistance. Oh well, I imagine I will keep with my current solution, unless someone knows how to create a category for components that does something like NSWrapCalendarComponents (properly figuring out leaps and DST, unpleasantness)